# Why is Cocos2d Scaling my Image Up?

Tags: image, background, cocos2d-iphone, scaling

This is very simple code, but I do not know why Cocos2D continues to scale my background image up by x2?

I'm using the Cocos2d Hello World template.  I haven't done anything to the code except delete everything inside of - (id) init

I then added this:

```
        //ADD BACKGROUND
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"justAbackground.png"];
    background.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
    [self addChild:background];
```

When I build and run it is double the size then what the image is supposed to be.

If I add:

```
background.scale = .5;
```

It is the exact size it's supposed to be.

The images pixel dimensions are exactly the same as the iPhone.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "exactly the same" what are them? maybe, you use retina texture with non-retina device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're confused by point vs pixel coordinates?

On a regular iPhone the point & pixel dimensions are equal and both amount to 480x320 pixels/points. On a Retina device the point coordinates remain 480x320 but the pixel coordinates are doubled to 960x640.

Now if you want to display a regular image using pixel coordinates on a Retina device, you must have Retina display mode *disabled*. Otherwise cocos2d will scale up any image without the -hd suffix to point dimensions.

The alternative is to have Retina display mode enabled and save your image with the -hd suffix (justAbackground-hd.png) with double the resolution.

Comment: Yes, that's what it was thank you.  I've since read the documentation about the -hd suffix http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3ahow_to_develop_retinadisplay_games_in_cocos2d

Comment: So, this may be obvious, but a corollary to this will be that: with Retina display enabled, and saving images without the -hd suffix, will mean that Cocos2d will report image content sizes to be half their pixel size.  Correct?

Comment: No, the opposite. The -hd images will be reported as half the size in points but you can always get the true pixel size too. Note that if you plan on saving the images in a user screenshot library of sorts, consider that users may be upgrading their device in the future thus you need to take into account that smaller screenshots need to be displayed correctly in the ui as well.